# Extract text from inner-most nested parentheses of string

Tags: r, regex, string-substitution

From the text string below, I am trying to extract a specific string subset.

```
string <- c("(Intercept)", "scale(AspectCos_30)", "scale(CanCov_500)", 
            "scale(DST50_30)", "scale(Ele_30)", "scale(NDVI_Tin_250)", "scale(Slope_500)", 
            "I(scale(Slope_500)^2)", "scale(SlopeVar_30)", "scale(CanCov_1000)", 
            "scale(NDVI_Tin_1000)", "scale(Slope_1000)", "I(scale(Slope_1000)^2)", 
            "scale(log(SlopeVar_30 + 0.001))", "scale(CanCov_30)", "scale(Slope_30)", 
            "I(scale(Slope_30)^2)")
```

A good result would return the  central text without any special characters, as shown below.

```
Good <- c("Intercept", "AspectCos", "CanCov", "DST50", "Ele", "NDVI", "Slope", "Slope",
            "SlopeVar", "CanCov", "NDVI", "Slope", "Slope", "SlopeVar", "CanCov" "Slope", "Slope")
```

Preferably however, the resulting string would account for the `^2` and `log` associated with 'Slope' and 'SlopeVar', respectively. Specifically, all strings containing `^2` would be converted to 'SlopeSq' and all strings containing `log` would be converted to 'SlopeVarPs', as show below.

```
Best <- c("Intercept", "AspectCos", "CanCov", "DST50", "Ele", "NDVI", "Slope", "SlopeSq",
          "SlopeVar", "CanCov", "NDVI", "Slope", "SlopeSq", "SlopeVarPs", "CanCov" "Slope", "SlopeSq")
```

I have a long, ugly, and inefficient code sequence that gets me nearly halfway to the Good result and would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a not-so-efficient coder, I like to have a chain of multiple regex to achieve the outcome (what each line of regex does is commented in each line):

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
string %>% 
  str_replace_all(".*log\\((.*?)(_.+?)?\\).*", "\\1Ps") %>% # deal with "log" entry
  str_replace_all(".*\\((.*?\\))", "\\1") %>% # delete anything before the last "(" 
  str_replace_all("(_\\d+)?\\)\\^2", "Sq") %>%  # take care of ^2
  str_replace_all("(_.+)?\\)?", "") -> "outcome" # remove extra characters in the end (e.g. "_00" and ")")


Best <- c("Intercept", "AspectCos", "CanCov", "DST50", "Ele", "NDVI", "Slope", "SlopeSq",
          "SlopeVar", "CanCov", "NDVI", "Slope", "SlopeSq", "SlopeVarPs", "CanCov","Slope", "SlopeSq")
all(outcome == Best)
## TRUE
```

Comment: Very much appreciated. Clear and informative! also did not know you could use the piping operator with stringer. Cool.

Comment: Piping is actually coming from `dplyr`. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be achieved with the package [stringr](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/index.html).

First, because you want the "central text" within the innermost parentheses. Thus the regex below rule out any text within parentheses containing parentheses. But I kept "log/^2" for later uses.

```
string_step <- str_extract(string,
                           "(log|)\\([^()]+\\)(\\^2|)")
```

Then I notice that anything after an underscore is truncated, but only phrases of alphebat (and digit) are kept. [Unlike \w (\w in R), which includes underscore, "[:alnum:]+" equals "[A-Za-z0-9]+"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), and is therefore used.

```
GoodMy <-
  str_extract(str_replace_all(string_step, "log|\\(|\\)|\\^2", ""),
              "[:alnum:]+")

BestMy <-
  paste0(Good, as.character(sapply(string_step, function(x) {
    if (str_detect(x, "log")) {
      "Ps"
    } else if (str_detect(x, "\\^2")) {
      "Sq"
    } else {
      ""
    }
  })))

all(Good == GoodMy, Best == BestMy) #yields True
```